# Calculations and Joins with Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a Point of Sale system that I'm trying to write a SQL query in a way that I can see check totals by tenders to reconcile with cash flows. Need to export the data to Excel so I can do final calculations. Unfortunately the schema is not mine and can't change it.  One problem I ran into is that there are cases where one check has multiple transactions involving various tenders, therefore I need to do some operations to get the correct totals.

The schema and sample data is here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d28656

The Excel table will look like this:

| CHECKID | TAX | PAYMENT | TENDER | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.35 | 5.35 | CASH | 5.35 |
| 2 | 1.40 | 21.40 | VISA | 10.70 |
| 2 |  |  | MC | 10.70 |

Ultimately, the last Excel total row (which I can write) should look like this:

```
Unique Checks = 2
Total Tax = 1.75
Total Payments = 26.75
Total CASH = 5.35
Total VISA = 10.70
Total MC   = 10.70
```

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question (which refers to one table).

If you are content with all the values in a single row, just use aggregation:

```
select count(distinct checkid),
       sum(tax),
       sum(payments),
       sum(case when tender = 'CASH' then amount else 0 end) as cash,
       sum(case when tender = 'VISA' then amount else 0 end) as visa,
       sum(case when tender = 'mc' then amount else 0 end) as mc
from t;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, you can find the actual tables that I need help with joining in the SQL Fiddle link.  Apologies if I wasn't clear enough. Thanks